# run VB type exe file from VB.NET from project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, vb6, exe

I have a question about running exe file in VB .NET project.

I previously read article 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/244460-how-to-run-a-exe-file-from-inside-a-vs2010-project/

to run exe file from inside of VB.NET project.

I used

> Process.Start("My.Resources\MyProgram.exe")
>   and
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\screen.exe")

to run exe file

however, it doesn't have any happen. Therefore, I assume that path was wrong to run exe file

here is what i did for running exe file

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists((My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\screen.exe")) Then
  MsgBox("yes")
        Process.Start((My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\screen.exe"))
    Else
        MsgBox("np")
    End If
```

I manually click exe file , it was running properly.
Moreover, I use if statement to make sure if there is file or not

it returns true which means there is a exe file.

However, when I run in Visual studio 2012 (VB.NET ) project.
There is no error and it doesn't seem to run file.

I am not really sure why this happen

Does anybody know why this happen ? thank

Comment: What's the return value of the call to Process.Start?

Comment: my sample exe file should take a screenshot. When I double click exe file. It was working. However, when I run my VB.NET project to run exe file. Just nothing happen...

Comment: I dont believe that exe file return it. exe file just take a screenshot

Comment: What MsgBox gets shown?
Also, try saving the return value of `Process.Start` to a `Diagnostics.Process` variable, put a breakpoint there and check the runtime values of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

i already test for this, and it run in my local pc.
Make sure you have correct path for exe file.

```
Process.Start("FolderPath\MyProgram.exe")
```

please check this site to download the code example for this.
[Example Code](http://xdeddyh.blogspot.com/2014/02/example-code-process-startvisual-studio.html)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, resources are not files so you can't execute them using Process.Start.  That will execute a file only so you would need to extract your resource, which is just bytes within your own program file, and save it as a separate file.  That's a security issue on Windows though, so may not even be allowed.

As for an actual EXE not running properly, one possible cause is an invalid working directory.  Try creating a ProcessStartInfo object and setting its WorkingDirectory property to the folder containing the EXE that you're running.  That can solve issues with programs that look in their working directory for dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear for me what you really need, if execute a resource or execute an existing executable file.

To start an exe that is in your resources you can load it to disk like this:

```
' Load Resource To Disk
' ( By Elektro )
'
' Usage Examples:
' LoadResourceToDisk(My.Resources.Program, "C:\Program.exe")
' Process.Start("C:\Program.exe")
'
''' <summary>
''' Loads a resource to disk.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Resource">
''' Indicates the resource to load.
''' </param>
''' <param name="TargetFile">
''' Indicates the target file to save the resource.
''' The target file is overwritten.
''' </param>
''' <returns>
''' <c>true</c> if operation succeeds, <c>false</c> otherwise.
''' </returns>
''' <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
Private Function LoadResourceToDisk(ByVal Resource As Byte(),
                                    ByVal TargetFile As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim BufferFileStream As New IO.FileStream(TargetFile, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
        BufferFileStream.Write(Resource, 0, Resource.Length)
        BufferFileStream.Close()
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)
        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

Usage:

```
  LoadResourceToDisk(My.Resources.Program, "C:\Program.exe")
  Process.Start("C:\Program.exe")
```

And to start a existing file you can do:

```
Private Sub Test() Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ExePath As String =
    IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Screen.exe")

    Dim Result As Integer

    Using p As New Process()

        With p.StartInfo
            .FileName = ExePath
            .Arguments = ""
        End With

        p.Start()
        p.WaitForExit()

        Result = p.ExitCode

    End Using

    MsgBox(String.Format("ExitCode: {0}", Result))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\FilesNameToSaveTo.exe", My.Resources.ResourceFilesName)


Process.Start(Application.Startpath & "\FilesNameToSaveTo.exe")
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.